# Combinations of up to n out of m elements - Order DOESN'T matter

Tags: combinations

Let's say I have the following 10 distinct items: {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}.

How many combinations are there if I can choose UP TO 10 items and order does not matter and items cannot be repeated?

I'm thinking that it is simply the sum of all the C(n,r)s, correct?

r0 = 1
r1 = 10
r2 = 45
r3 = 120
r4 = 210
r5 = 252
r6 = 210
r7 = 120
r8 = 45
r9 = 10
r10 = 1

Thus, 1024 combinations???

I appreciate any help... These always trip me up!

Comment: As there are only 10 elements on your set in the first place, what you're doing is counting the number of parts of the set. Essentially, how you do it is just go through each element and pick it, or don't. That leaves you with $2^{|X|}=2^{10}$.

Comment: Great! Thanks, @Bcpicao.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s correct. It’s equivalent to asking how many subsets of a set with $m$ elements are possible with size no more than $n$. We can either choose $0$ elements, or $1$ element, or $2$, or $3$ and so on till $n$ elements. The answer would be then be $$\sum_{i=0}^n {m \choose i}$$

Comment: Thanks, @Tavish!